# How to connect WordPress to AWS Aurora serverless MySQL?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-aurora

I want to get advantage is Aurora serverless since my current DB has over 1 million records. I can connect to it from my computer via ssh to ec2 in the same vpc with Aurora.

I installed WP in the same ec2, yet WP can't connect to it, any idea is it supported, or it should be used only with serverless platform by API?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use AWS aurora serverless with WordPress as well as other PHP stacks, WordPress is compatible with MySQL 5.6 which serverless built on

the only thing I can think of is to make sure your database security group has access to the ec2 server and both are under same VPC

https://www.jeremydaly.com/aurora-serverless-the-good-the-bad-and-the-scalable/